# JavaScript array reduce start from index

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

This problem has been bugging me for a while now and I can't seem to find an answer in web.

Is it possible to use Array reduce method starting from a certain index?

simple example

```
var studentGrades = ["John Doe", "Some School", 6, 7, 8, 7, 9, 9];
```

If I need to loop over only integers in *studentGrades*, I can do that with a simple for loop

```
for(var i = 2; i < studentGrades.length; i++) {
  // do stuff here ...
}
```

But let's say I would need get an average grade which is sum of all integers divided by integers count. If Array contained only integers, then there would be no problem using *reduce*.

```
var onlyIntegersArr = [5,2,3,4];
var averageGrade = onlyIntegersArr.reduce(function(a,b){
  return a + b;
}) / onlyIntegersArr.length;
```

However if I know that for whatever reasons I need to skip the first two Array elements and start from index Array[2].

So for example I would apply *reduce* to *studentGrades*, but only starting from index studentGrades[2].

Is that possible with *reduce*?

Thank you for solutions, I like *slice* approach, but I prefer not using a new method in this case.

e.g.

```
var average = studentGrades.reduce(function(a,b,i){
  return i >= 2 ? a+b : 0;
}) / (studentGrades.length - 2);
```

Comment: `array.slice(2).reduce(...`

Comment: How about `if` condition ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)'s 3rd argument is an index, here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/dg5p570a/)

```
var averageGrade = onlyIntegersArr.reduce(function (a, b, c) {
    if (c >= 2) {
        return a + b;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
});
```

if array has more non-numeric items after second index then check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/dg5p570a/1/)

```
var studentGrades = ["John Doe", "Some School", 6, 7, 8, 7, 9, 9, "Some School"];
var averageGrade = studentGrades.reduce(function (a, b, c) {
    if (c >= 2 && !isNaN(b)) {
        return a + b;
    } else if (c >= 2) {
        return a + 0;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
})
alert(averageGrade);
```

Comment: It will fail for this: `var studentGrades = ["John Doe", "Some School", 6, 7,'test'];`

Comment: @RayonDabre true, but that is not what OP is asking. Anyways, let me put a check for isNaN also if OP has asked for it.

Comment: I will accept this solution as it fits my problem most. I don't need to use a new array method, but instead just use the index parameter in reduce method. I had somehow overlooked it.

Comment: I like shorter solutions, like `onlyIntegersArr.reduce((a, b, c) => (c >= 2 ? a + b : 0))`

Comment: I agree, but I like this solution as it's the only one pointing out to use reduce index argument.

Comment: @Tushar Thanks for the editing and making it more concise and readable.

Answer (score 11):

If you know for a fact that you want to skip the first `n` elements, you can use [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Using ES2015 [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
var sum = array.slice(n).reduce((a, b) => a + b);
```

```js
var studentGrades = ["John Doe", "Some School", 6, 7, 8, 7, 9, 9];
var sum = studentGrades.slice(2).reduce((a, b) => a + b);

document.body.innerHTML = 'SUM is = ' + sum;
```

In ES5, the same code can be written using anonymous function.

```
var sum = array.slice(n).reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
});
```

```js
var studentGrades = ["John Doe", "Some School", 6, 7, 8, 7, 9, 9];
var sum = studentGrades.slice(2).reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
});

document.body.innerHTML = 'SUM is = ' + sum;
```

for the case you mentioned, of only adding up numeric values, regardless of where in the array they are - you could do something like

```
var sum = array.reduce(function(result, v) {
    return result + (parseFloat(v) || 0);
}, 0);
```

```js
var studentGrades = ["John Doe", "Some School", 6, 7, 8, 7, 9, 9];
var sum = studentGrades.reduce(function(result, v) {
    return result + (parseFloat(v) || 0);
}, 0);

document.body.innerHTML = 'SUM is = ' + sum;
```

Comment: @fast, yes, it does, a problem for sure if you have billions of elements

Comment: kudos to @Tushar for the hard work he put in to editing the answer to make it look and read so good

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure you always need only index 2 onwards, then this is sufficient

```
var onlyIntegersArr = studentGrades.slice(2);
var averageGrade = onlyIntegersArr.reduce(function(a,b){
    return a + b;
}) / onlyIntegersArr.length;
```

If, however, you want to get all integers, then you need to filter the array

```
var onlyIntegersArr = studentGrades.filter(function(val) {
    return (val === parseInt(val, 10));
});
var averageGrade = onlyIntegersArr.reduce(function(a,b){
    return a + b;
}) / onlyIntegersArr.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you overcomplicate things? Why not:

```
function avg(arr)
{
     var sum = 0;
     var l = 0;
     for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
     {
        if(isNaN(1*arr[i])) continue;
        sum += arr[i];
        l++;
     }
     return sum/l;
}
```

Maybe you need to think about keeping the data in object, where all the grades are in a separate array. And other data be in properties. You can serialize it from the array you have, and then work with the object.